# Cube roots in Python programming

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first programming class and this week we worked on while loops. We have a homework example trying to code for a cube root. This is what I have so far but I cannot get my code to actually run the program. I'm not getting any errors. Is there something I'm missing?

```
def cbrt(nub):
    loopn=1
    x0=1
    loplT=1000
    exTol=0.000001
    while loopn<=loplT:
        x=(1/3)+((2*x0)+(num/x0*x0))
        if abs(x - x0)< exTol:
            return x
        else:
            x0 = x
            loopn = loopn + 1
            return False
        print(cbrt(8))
```

Comment: Your indentation is off, maybe from copy/paste? Also your function argument is called "nub" but inside the function you reference it as "num", maybe a typo?

Comment: `print(cbrt(8))` seems to be inside the definition of `cbrt`.

Comment: get rid of `return false` (or maybe your indentation is broken?) (`num` also appears to be non-existant)

Comment: Just FYI you can compute the cube root (approximatly) with `num ** (1/3)` or if you have NumPy you can access the C library `math` function using `np.cbrt`. :)

Comment: Something looks fishy about `(num/x0*x0)`

Comment: Correct formula is: `x = (2. * x0 + num / (x0*x0)) / 3.0` - see @CaryShindell answer

Comment: You could also use x = x0 - (x0 ** 3 - num) / (3.0 * x0 ** 2), as per http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52628.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def cbrt(num): # not nub
    loopn=1
    x0=1
    loplT=1000
    exTol=0.000001
    while loopn<=loplT:
        x=(1/3)+((2*x0)+(num/x0*x0)) # this estimation method is wrong!
        # I think you want `(1/3)_*_ ((2*old_est)+num/(old_est*old_est))
        # notice parenthesis and multiplies instead of adds 1/3 ... also make sure you are using python 3 or 1/3 will always equal zero...
        if abs(x - x0)< exTol:
            return x
        else:
            x0 = x
            loopn = loopn + 1
    return False # dont return False inside your loop ...

print(cbrt(8))
```

there you go ... rember in python WHITESPACE IS VERY IMPORTANT!!!

Answer (score 2):

You called the function inside of itself but not outside, so the function never runs. You need to add a line outside of the function to call it. You also shouldn't return False in your loop:

```
def cbrt(num): # changed from nub to num
    loopn=1
    x0=1
    loplT=1000
    exTol=0.000001
    while loopn<=loplT:
        x = (2. * x0 + num/(x0*x0)) / 3.0 # fixed estimation method
        if abs(x - x0)< exTol:
            return x
        else:
            x0 = x
            loopn = loopn + 1
    return False # return false outside loop
print(cbrt(8)) # call function outside of function
```

Comment: this is only one of the problems with his code afaik ... `num` is undefined ... and it will always return false .... (well unless the `nub` is 1)

Comment: i think "nub" is a typo, its never referenced, and it should be "num"

Comment: @MarkM I don't see the issue

Comment: @JoranBeasley, JavoSN thanks, see edits

Comment: Something looks fishy about `(num/x0*x0)`

Comment: @AGNGazer good point. Perhaps it's supposed to be `(num/(x0*x0))`?

Comment: `x = (2. * x0 + num / (x0*x0)) / 3.0`

Comment: lol @AGNGazer ... tbh we could have left at least one thing for OP to solve on their own :P but way to know your order of operations (and that adding 1/3 made no sense in general)